# file zip/tar in linux at specific location

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tar

I want to zip a set of directories and files on my centos 8 VM.
There are 3 directories and 1 file which I want to zip in such a way that only env.conf file will move to /etc/env.txt after unzipping it and remaining directories will be unzipped at current location.
Is there any way to achieve this.

```
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root       114 Feb 25 12:40 config
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root       340 Feb 25 09:01 env.conf
drwxr-xr-x. 9 root root      4096 Feb 28 05:11 platform
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root       135 Feb 28 07:49 install
```

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. in fact this is considered a vulnerability if you could do that.

Imagine you download a zip file from some website. and after you unzip it in a temp folder. It registers itself as a service by writing a file in `/etc` somewhere, and gets control over your pc.
Example: [zip-slip](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/zip-slip/)

You could however create a one-liner that extracts and moves the file wherever you want like this:

```sh
unzip <filename> && mv env.conf /etc/env.txt
```